# How to change autocomplete behavior in PyCharm/IntellijIdea?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

It's very annoying when you rewriting some variable, attribute or function from it's middle and PyCharm let there the rest of the old string.

My cursor is between 's' and '_' and I pressed ctrl+space:

[image]

Now, when I use suggested completion, it doesn't remove the rest of the function.

[image]

Is it possible to make it remove the rest of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the completion popup is active, pressing Enter inserts the text of the selected item at caret, and pressing Tab replaces the identifier after caret with the text of the selected item. So you should press Tab instead of Enter in this situation.