# Stop PyCharm's completion from replacing word right of the cursor when tab completing

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm, tab completion replaces the word right of the cursor by default. This happens to me often when I insert some function into existing code. For example, if I want to add a call to `foobar` around an existing `x+1` expression, I would type

[image]

which brings up the completion options. The result after tab-completing is

[image]

with `x` having been overwritten. Is there a way to make PyCharm's completion stop removing words right to the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>? It should do exactly what you want: put corresponding function after cursor without replacing other code.

By the way, recently other guy was asking how to do [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137682/how-to-change-autocomplete-behavior-in-pycharm-intellijidea/44142304#44142304) thing :)

Answer (score 3):

At least in my version of Pycharm, the option can be changed under Settings->Keymap in "Choose Lookup Item" and "Choose Lookup Item Replace"

[image]

I don't ever expect to see text replaced when doing tab completion, so I've moved "Tab" to "Choose Lookup Item."